# How to specify where to get IP from in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ip

Okay so we use some simple IP authentication with htaccess for a folder on our site:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1
```

But with the new CDN we are on, the actual users IP address comes through in a different server variable, lets say:

```
$_SERVER['absolutely_true_ip'];
```

whereas

```
$_SERVER['remote_addr'];
```

is not the users true IP

Is there anyway to tell htaccess where to look for the IP we want to authenticate with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

X-FORWARDED-FOR is used by most servers (CDNs, Proxys) to send the originating ip (the users ip). So this should to the job:

```
SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR 1.1.1.1 allow
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=allow
```

If your CDN has a different variable name, just edit the first line.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to allow multiple ip's, just duplicate the first line:

```
SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR 1.1.1.1 allow
SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR 2.2.2.2 allow
SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR 3.3.3.3 allow
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=allow
```

Comment: Could you modify your answer to accommodate a few different IP's? Thanks.